# Round border with light effect in QML

Tags: qt, qml

[image: round border with lighting effect]

I'm starting to do some tests with Qt using QtQuick. I'd like to know if there's a way to achieve this kind of border effect in plain QML. I've seen something about QtQuick3D, but it sounds like too much... this is just to get some visual effects in an office application. This application will most likely be ran in low end desktops, and I don't want to get any performance penalty for the effects. But please, correct if I'm wrong about 3D being too much.

The straightforward alternative seems to be the BorderImage object, but I want to be sure there's no way in plain QML (i.e., without external images).

I appreciate any help.

Comment: `BorderImage` is the way. Another would probably be a reimplementation of effects you applied in Photoshop.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Maybe you try implement this with [`ShaderEfect`](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-5/qml-qtquick-shadereffect.html)?
This code is not efficient, but should work as expected on today's low performance graphic cards (OpenGL 3+) and with Qt5.2 (Qt 5.0 with some bypass):

```
ShaderEffect {
    x:50
    y:50
    width: 500
    height: 100

    property color color: "grey"
    property vector2d size: Qt.vector2d(width,height)
    property real lightsize: 5
    property real round:  50

    vertexShader: "
        uniform highp mat4 qt_Matrix;
        attribute highp vec4 qt_Vertex;
        uniform highp vec2 size;
        varying highp vec2 coord;
        void main() {
            coord = qt_Vertex.xy;
            gl_Position = qt_Matrix * qt_Vertex;
        }"
    fragmentShader: "
        varying highp vec2 coord;
        uniform highp vec2 size;
        uniform lowp vec4 color;
        uniform lowp float qt_Opacity;
        uniform lowp float lightsize;
        uniform lowp float round;
        void main() {
            float dx=0.0f;
            float dy=0.0f;
            if( coord.x < round )
                dx = coord.x-round;
            else if( coord.x > (size.x - round) )
                dx = round - (size.x - coord.x);
            if( coord.y < round )
                dy = coord.y-round;
            else if( coord.y > (size.y - round) )
                dy = round-(size.y - coord.y);
            float distance= sqrt(dx*dx+dy*dy);
            float ilumination = dot(vec2(dx, dy)/distance,vec2(-0.5f,-0.5f)) * 0.5 * smoothstep( lightsize, 0.0f , abs(distance-(round-lightsize*0.5)) );
            lowp vec4 insidecolor = (vec4(ilumination, ilumination , ilumination,0.0f)+color) * smoothstep( round, round-2.0f, distance);
            gl_FragColor =  insidecolor * qt_Opacity;
        }"

}
```

[image: Rounded Box]

Comment: Question asks explicitely for low perf devices, so you shouldn't use ShaderEffect, look at my answer : it looks like a 3D effect but it's not !

Comment: @TheBootroo You right, but even todays midrange smart-phones have enoughs FLOPS per pixel. And your answer looks flat ;->

Answer (score 3):

I was able to reproduce the exact same effect using no effect at all, only Gradient :

```
import QtQuick 2.0;

Rectangle {
    width: 640;
    height: 95;
    color: "black";

    Item {
        id: fakeRect;
        height: 80;
        width: 480;
        anchors.centerIn: parent;

        property alias color      : fakeBackground.color;
        property int   borderSize : 4;

        Rectangle {
            id: fakeBorder;
            radius: Math.min (width, height) * 0.5;
            antialiasing: true;
            gradient: Gradient {
                GradientStop { position: 0.0; color: Qt.lighter (fakeRect.color, 1.65); }
                GradientStop { position: 1.0; color: Qt.darker  (fakeRect.color, 1.65); }
            }
            anchors.fill: parent;

            Rectangle {
                id: fakeBackground;
                color: "#5A5A5A";
                radius: Math.min (width, height) * 0.5;
                antialiasing: true;
                anchors {
                    fill: parent;
                    margins: fakeRect.borderSize;
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Quite easy in fact, just don't use Rectangle.border, emulate it with custom component !

Comment: I like the simplicity of this solution, but it doesn't quite reproduce the light effect. Note that light seems to come from top left.